# Showing that every subgroup of a metacyclic group is metacyclic

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have tried to prove that every subgroup of a metacyclic group is metacyclic (where a group $G$ is metacyclic if it has a normal cyclic subgroup $C$ such that $G/C$ is cyclic).  I believe I have a proof, but it seems awfully piecemeal.  Is the following attempt at a proof valid, and if so, is there a more elegant proof?

Let $G$ be metacyclic with normal cyclic subgroup $C$ such that $G/C$ is cyclic.  Let $H \le G$.

If $H \ge C$, then $H/C$ is a subgroup of $G/C$, and so necessarily cyclic.  It follows that $H$ is metacyclic.

Now suppose that $H \le C$.  Then $H$ is cyclic and so it clearly metacyclic.

Next, suppose that $H$ is not as above and $H \cap C > 1$.  Since $C \triangleleft G$ we have $(H \cap C) \triangleleft H$ and $H \cap C$ (being a subgroup of $C$) is cyclic.  Then we have that $H/(H \cap C) \cong HC/C$ is a subgroup of $G/C$ and so $H$ is metacyclic by the above argument.

Finally, if $H \cap C = 1$, then no nontrivial element of $H$ is in the kernel of the canonical homomorphism $\pi: G \to G/C$, and so there is an isomorphic copy of it in $G/C$.  Since $G/C$ is cyclic, $H$ must be cyclic, and so it is metacyclic.

It follows that every subgroup of $G$ is metacyclic.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not doing all in one strike? For any subgroup $\;H\le G\;$ :

$$HC/C\cong H/(H\cap C)$$

But $\;H\cap C\le C\;$ and it is thus a cyclic subgroup *of* $\;H\;$, and also $\;HC/C\le G/C\;$ is cyclic as a subgroup of a cyclic group...

Comment: Thanks.  My next question is 'when will I learn to consistently think a little bit harder?'!  I realized all the cases came down to the intersection $H \cap C$, but I didn't think to just apply the Diamond Theorem in every case.